# Where are the MathJax LaTeX symbols/environments documented?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

At the following link in the MathJax documentation it lists the supported LaTeX symbols alphabetically that it supports, followed by the set of supported environments...

http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/tex.html#symbols

My question is where are each of these symbols/enviornments described and documented?

For example, where is the definitive description of the `\above` symbol ?

Comment: Is the focus here MathJax or the more general syntax for math mode commands for (La)TeX? The latter is on-topic, but MathJax-specifics are off-topic as MathJax does not actually use TeX, only LaTeX-like math commands.

Comment: The commands and their usage are explained in detail in [this page](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) that is linked to the page you mentioned.

Comment: The advantage of just typing TeX equations in html that MathJax provides is so awesome that it never occurred to me that this might be off-topic.  I assumed that the original question was aimed at extending MathJax support for LaTeX.  I think egreg's answer was more appropriate.

Comment: @JosephWright: Sorry Joseph I disagree.  The LaTeX-like features of MathJax are most certainly a TeX-related tool, and as such are on topic at tex.stackexchange.com, as per point 4 of FAQ.

Comment: @user1131467: No, it's not really a TeX-related tool, because it doesn't use Tex or is used together with it. It only uses a subset of the TeX syntax, plus maybe some extra things. A question about the description of LaTeX commands is on-topic, but MathJax documentation would be off-topic. Now you ask about a description for TeX commands (which is on-topic) but for a different software (off-topic), so your question is kind of in the gray area.

Comment: @user1131467: See also [How do we feel about MathJaX/jsMath/other spin-offs?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/272)

Comment: the link in the question is dead, 404

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Web page

http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm

has a very detailed explanation of each LaTeX command that is interpreted by MathJax.

The commands are of course explained in the LaTeX manual or in many user's guide; the commands that are labeled "AMS" are described in the [documentation of amsmath](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).

A particularly recommended guide about math in LaTeX is ["Math mode"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) by Herbert Voß (although more focused on usage in LaTeX).

Answer (score 3):

The definitive answers are in the JavaScript source code.  The best way to examine the source is to download the source from GitHub

```
git clone http://github.com/mathjax/MathJax
```

Once you have the source files, then it is possible to see exactly how `\above` is implemented and you'll find that `\above` is defined in `unpacked/jax/input/TeX/jax.js` as 'Over', which in turn is implemented using the following JavaScript

```
Over: function (name,open,close) {
  var mml = STACKITEM.over().With({name: name});
  if (open || close) {
    mml.open = open; mml.close = close;
  } else if (name.match(/withdelims$/)) {
    mml.open  = this.GetDelimiter(name);
    mml.close = this.GetDelimiter(name);
  }
  if (name.match(/^\\above/)) {mml.thickness = this.GetDimen(name)}
  else if (name.match(/^\\atop/) || open || close) {mml.thickness = 0}
  this.Push(mml);
},
```

which is pretty inscrutable.  Simpler TeX constructs like `\alpha` are simply mapped to the corresponding unicode value

```
alpha:        '03B1',
```