# Packages in StackExchange -- possible? If so, how?

Tags: packages

Can you use packages *on math.stackexchange*?

The help associated with the editor does not mention packages, so I am guessing it's not possible.

But if it is, how? I am particularly interested in the *centernot* package at the moment.

If there is documentation or a prior question for this, please direct me to it -- I have searched for this answer with no luck. There are responses on package use on tex.stackexchange, but they do not work as-is on stackexchange.

Finally, is this a good place to ask questions about TeX usage *in stackexchange*?  When I tried such a question on meta.math.stackexchange, I got scolded and sent here. Well, it was a generic TeX question, and this one is specific to stackexchange.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a great place to ask this, as the automatic conversion your seeing is not actually TeX. StackExchange uses a system called MathJax, which is a way of converting LaTeX-like math input into something human-readable in web browsers. But it does not use TeX, and so there are no packages.

Comment: BTW, you might find [Where are the MathJax LaTeX symbols/environments documented?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49330/where-are-the-mathjax-latex-symbols-environments-documented) useful.

Comment: Looking at the question on maths-SX (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3995/2907), you were referred here because you didn't make it clear that you were asking about MathJaX so someone clearly thought you meant in LaTeX, not MathJaX.  The point is that as MathJaX does not use TeX but only emulates a part of it, expertise with TeX doesn't help with knowing about MathJaX, so this isn't a likely place to get answers and you'd be better off asking on the MathJaX support sites.

Comment: Ah, MathjaX is not TeX -- fundamental insight I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: This -- http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html -- page is dynamite -- you draw a symbol freehand and it guesses (quite well for me so far) what the MathjaX symbol might be.